# Js scipt getting crashed if i change the slider value again and again. I need to refresh it again and again everytime it crashes

Tags: javascript, html, graph

Basically I am using html5 slider to change the value. But after changing value few times, whole webpage is getting crashed. On changing the values of slider, it is calling one function every time. I am newbie here. Can anybody help me please?

Slider code is written below:

```
<input type="range" id="B1" name="B1" value="0" min="-2" max="2" step="0.1" onchange="JavaScript:main();" oninput="B1val.value = B1.value" />
```

I have used many sliders like the above one and drawing a graph with the help of the inputs from this slider. The main() function is placed in between  tags and is written below for reference ::

```
function main() {
    // lots more features are available, this is just a "hello world"
    // program.
    var b0 = document.getElementById("B0").value;
    var b1 = document.getElementById("B1").value;
    var b2 = document.getElementById("B2").value;
    var b3 = document.getElementById("B3").value;
    var b4 = document.getElementById("B4").value;
    var b5 = document.getElementById("B5").value;
    var b6 = document.getElementById("B6").value;
    var b7 = document.getElementById("B7").value;
    var b8 = document.getElementById("B8").value;
    var b9 = document.getElementById("B9").value;
    var b10 = document.getElementById("B10").value;
    var b11 = document.getElementById("B11").value;
    var b12 = document.getElementById("B12").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("funct").value;
    var f = document.getElementById("terms").value;
    var fun = document.getElementById("Target").value;;

    var b = 1;
    var e = 0;
    var g = 1;
    var h = 1;
    var j = 0;

    if(d == "sin" && f == "even"){
        document.getElementById("equat").innerHTML = "B2sin(2t)+B4sin(4t)+B6sin(6t)+B8sin(8t)+B10sin(10t)+....";
        document.getElementById("B0").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B1").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B3").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B5").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B7").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B9").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B11").disabled = true;
    }
    if(d == "sin" && f == "odd"){
        document.getElementById("equat").innerHTML = "B1sin(t)+B3sin(3t)+B5sin(5t)+B7sin(7t)+B9sin(9t)+....";
        document.getElementById("B0").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B2").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B4").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B6").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B8").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B10").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B12").disabled = true;
    }
    if(d == "sin" && f == "evenodd"){
        document.getElementById("equat").innerHTML = "B1sin(t)+B2sin(2t))+B3sin(3t)+B4sin(4t)+B5sin(5t)+...";}
    if(d == "cos" && f == "even"){
        document.getElementById("equat").innerHTML = "  (0.5)B0+B2cos(2t)+B4cos(4t)+B6cos(6t)+B8cos(8t)+...";
        document.getElementById("B1").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B3").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B7").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B9").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B11").disabled = true;
    }
    if(d == "cos" && f == "odd"){
        document.getElementById("equat").innerHTML = " B1cos(t)+B3cos(3t)+B5cos(5t)+B7cos(7t)+B9cos(9t)+...";
        document.getElementById("B0").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B2").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B4").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B6").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B8").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B10").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("B12").disabled = true;
    }
    if(d == "cos" && f == "evenodd"){
        document.getElementById("equat").innerHTML = "   (0.5)B0+B1cos(t)+B2cos(2t)+B3cos(3t)+B4cos(4t)+...";}

    if(d == "cos" && f == "evenodd") {j = 1;}
    else if(d == "cos" && f == "even") {j = 1;}
    else {j = 0;}

    if(d == "sin") {b = "sin"; d = 1;}
    if(d == "cos") {b = "cos"; d = 1;}
    if(d == "sincos") {d = 0; e = 1;}
    if(f == "even") {g = 0; h = 1;}
    if(f == "odd") {g = 1; h = 0;}

    myPlot = new Waveplot(document.getElementById('myPlot'));
    myPlot.addPlot(j+"(0.5)*"+b0+"+"+d+"("+b1+"*"+g+"*"+b+"(0.5*3.14159*x)"+"+"+b2+"*"+h+"*"+b+"(2*3.14159*0.5*x)"+"+"+b3+"*"+g+"*"+b+"(3*3.14159*0.5*x)"+"+"+b4+"*"+h+"*"+b+"(4*3.14159*0.5*x)"+"+"+b5+"*"+g+"*"+b+"(5*3.14159*0.5*x)"+"+"+b6+"*"+h+"*"+b+"(6*3.14159*0.5*x)"+"+"+b7+"*"+g+"*"+b+"(7*3.14159*0.5*x)"+"+"+b8+"*"+h+"*"+b+"(8*3.14159*0.5*x)"+"+"+b9+"*"+g+"*"+b+"(9*3.14159*0.5*x)"+"+"+b10+"*"+h+"*"+b+"(10*3.14159*0.5*x)"+"+"+b11+"*"+g+"*"+b+"(11*3.14159*0.5*x)"+"+"+b12+"*"+h+"*"+b+"(12*3.14159*0.5*x)"+")",WAVEPLOT_TYPE_FUNCTION);
    myPlot.addPlot(fun+"(x)",WAVEPLOT_TYPE_FUNCTION);
    myPlot.reDraw();
}
```

Comment: The problem is in the Javascript `main()` function, which you haven't shown. BTW, you don't need to put `JavaScript:` in `onchange` attributes. That's only needed when you put Javascript code in an attribute that normally contains a URL, like `href`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I have removed Javascript but problem still remains the same. I have also added main() function for your reference. Can you please check the issue again.

Comment: Try to catch elements, var B1 = document.getElementById('b1'), then just B1.disable() or whatever

Comment: I suspect the problem is in `Waveplot`, it may have a memory leak that causes problems when you keep creating new instances. Maybe you should be modifying the existing plot instead of creating a new one each time.

Comment: Yes Barmar, i also think so. It is memory leak. May i know how i can modify the existing wave plot instead of creating the new one.